# Prime and rational numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, rational-numbers

I came across the following question while studying that is stumping me. Can anyone please help me solve it?

Let "$a$" be a prime number greater than $10,000$ and let $x=\sqrt{a}$. Which of the following expressions represents a rational number?

F) $x/2$
G) $\sqrt{x}$
H) $2x$
J) $x^2$
K) $x+2 $

Comment: We know that roots of integers are either integers, or rationals. Since a is a prime number, it cannot be a perfect square, implying that x is irrational. Also it's typically good form to explain what you've tried so far on this website!

Comment: I wasn't sure where to start on this one. I know that if "a" is a prime number it cannot be a perfect square, but why does that make x irrational? Furthermore, the answer is J, but I just read that squaring an irrational number doesn't always make it rational.

Comment: While squaring an irrational doesn't always get a rational, squaring *a square root of a rational* will. We have $x^2=(\sqrt{a})^2=a$.

Comment: This question could've been made more challenging and interesting if instead of $x^2$, they'd made that option something like $(x + \sqrt 2)(x - \sqrt 2)$. I would've done that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $x$ is rational. Then we can express $x$ as:
$$x=\frac{p}{q}$$
where $p,q$ are co-prime integers. $x=\sqrt a$ can be written as:
$$x^2=a$$
$$\frac{p^2}{q^2}=a$$
$$p^2=aq^2$$
As the prime $a$ divides the RHS, it divides the LHS too. $p=ka$ for some integer $k$. Substituting:
$$k^2a^2=aq^2$$
$$k^2a=q^2$$
Hence, $a$ also divides $q$, which implies $p$ and $q$ are not co-prime. Contradiction.

Thus, $x$ is irrational.

We can go ahead proving  by contradiction that F,G,H,K are all irrational.

J is the answer as $x^2=a$ is prime and thus integer and rational.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure!